# Can Dark Delirium be used to charm an opponent into hurting itself?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, illusion, charmed

The *Dark Delirium* Warlock ability plunges a creature into an Illusory Realm and it rolls a Wisdom Save. Upon a failure, the creature is either Frightened or Charmed by the Warlock.

Things about the Illusion:

- The entire world you are now in is the Illusion. For the target, it looks like they've been transported between Planes or teleported somewhere.
- You and you alone decide the appearance of the Illusion.
- The creature can see and hear only itself, the Illusion, and you.

#### Question

If I am in combat with a creature in a battlefield with dangerous terrain, can I use the illusion to make the creature think the dangerous terrain isn't there, and then convince the charmed creature to walk towards me (or a Frightened one to run away from me) and into dangerous terrain?

- Let's say that I am interacting with an Orc whom, for whatever reason, I have to kill, and there are ledges between me and my target. I, as an Archfey-Pact Warlock of 14th Level, cast Dark Delirium on that Orc. The Orc fails the saving throw and is plunged into the Illusion and Charmed. When describing the Illusion, I describe one that looks like an ethereal marshy sort of place without any sort of ledge between us.

  Can I convince (through social checks) the now-Charmed (and probably-curious) Orc to walk towards me, even if that would move the Orc over the precipice that divides us since the Orc can no longer see the edge?

  Would it be any different if we were not fighting before the spell was cast (say, the Orc was a sentry who was previously unaware of my presence) versus if we were?

Mythologically-speaking (respecting to real-world mythology and not Forgotten Realms Lore), there have been several stories where a Fey creature of some sort has convinced an unfortunate traveler that they were walking on a path when, in fact, that traveler was actually sinking into a bog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

The ability places the creature in the charmed or frightened [condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions) and allows it to " see and hear only itself, the illusion, and you".

Now, the frightened condition does not force the creature to move - it just limits its options when moving (i.e. not closer to the warlock) so its not really useful for this.

The charmed condition relevantly states "The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature". So if you want to get the creature something that will lead to it harming itself you have advantage on any ability check to do this.

Note that this would probably be a Deception or Intimidation check rather than a Persuasion check because you are *not* telling the creature the truth.

Note that you can do this with anything that imposes the charmed condition.

The DM must set the DC of the check and you make your attempt with advantage. I would suggest that since the creature cannot see the hazard the DC should be lower than if you try to do this with say, the [Charm Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person) spell: perhaps medium (DC15) instead of Nearly Impossible (DC30).

**Note:** 5e *does not* impose the limitation on self harm that some prior editions did as a general rule. As always, specific overrides general so check the particular ability that creates the charmed condition.

Comment: As a side question, would you consider the Frightened condition to give Advantage on Intimidation checks?

Comment: @SeraphsWrath Don’t ask questions in comments - that’s what questions are for.